# MST in linear time

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm preparing to the final exam in Algorithms and I have a question, that i hope you guys can help me with.

Given an undirected Graph with weights between 1 to 100, how can I find the Minimum Spanning Spanning Tree in a linear time ?

Comment: Use Prim's algorithm. Since the weights of edges are bounded, you can replace a standard priority queue by an array of length 100. By doing so, DeleteMin/DecreaseKey can be done in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) with [disjoint-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) and sort edges using [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), because your weights are limited.

Comment: Kruskal uses Union which is log*(n) that's why kruskal doesn't work.

Comment: @JayMar No, if you use [disjoint-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) then Kruskal takes O(E * α(V)), where α is the inverse of the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), which is extremely slowly growing, so for any practical problem it takes O(E).